# Entity Framework Code First Migrations MySQL Views

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-migrations

My target is to populate DataGrid using Entity Framework. User will see one table which will combine columns of two database tables. I followed tutorial and activated migrations in my code first approach project and so on.

Now I am dealing with following error:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[V_Mo' at line 1

I guess that this is SQL Server syntax but I am using MySQL database. I fail to convert the query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[V_MovieActors]'))
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = 
       N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_MovieActors]
         AS 
             SELECT 
                 NEWID() AS Id, dbo.Movie.Title, dbo.Movie.ReleaseDate, 
                 dbo.Actor.FirstName + '' '' + dbo.Actor.LastName AS Actor, 
                 dbo.Actor.DateOfBirth
             FROM            
                 dbo.Actor 
             INNER JOIN 
                 dbo.Movie ON dbo.Actor.Id = dbo.Movie.Actor_Id'
```

Comment: First things first, you have enabled migrations, added a migration and are now trying to apply it (update-database) ? Make sure the correct project is selected in the console. Then you can move on to making sure your context, DbSets etc are correct.

Comment: Everything what you mention seems to be correct on my side.